# Change text color of webpage using drop down list

Tags: html

i'm trying to figure out how  to change the text color of a webpage using a drop down menu,
i have manage to successfully change the background color using the drop down menu which is 
the following code:

could anyone advise me on how to accomplish this?

Comment: So, your code works but you still need help?

Comment: yes it is working fine. What is the problem for it

Comment: Yes, the code above works but that is to change the background color of the webpage, what i need help with is on how to change the text color on a webpage using a drop down list

Comment: @Jordan and PSR, read the question... Jc, are you looking for homework help? I think there are lots of duplicates on SO... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=change+text+color+%5Bjavascript%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, move your javascript out into a separate function (which is just good practise, and makes it easier to read/update) and set your onChange(); to call that function, with the value of the select being passed to it.

Then write your function to be something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function updateTextColour(value) {
                document.body.style.color = '#' + value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>Change the background color:
            <select name="backGround" size="1" onChange="updateTextColour(this.value)">
                <option value="000000">[Black]</option>
                <option value="FF0400">[Red]</option>
                <option value="EFE800">[Yellow]</option>
                <option value="05EF00">[Green]</option>
                <option value="0206FF">[Blue]</option>
                <option value="FFFFFF" selected>[White]</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, you can actually use the [words for these colours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names)... experiment with the following JS:

```
document.body.style.color = "red";
document.body.style.color = "blue";
document.body.style.color = "grey";
```

Comment: @msturdy thanks for your help, you have made it easier for me to understand,

Comment: @Antony It works fine; JSFiddle has trouble executing functions like that.  Try running it locally.

Comment: @HyperAnthony I posted a wrong link, it should be http://jsfiddle.net/JRx7x/2/ (the non-working solution). His answer missed a critical "#" that makes it non-functional in jsFiddle. Try http://jsfiddle.net/JRx7x/3/ (a working solution).

Comment: Thanks @antony, I've updated my answer!  I had tested it locally, and it worked fine... I guess Chrome is a little more forgiving :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the text color of the `<body>` element:

```
document.body.style.color="#"+backGround.options[backGround.selectedIndex].value
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EedAU/1/).